# Convergence and Divergence of Series $\frac{({a+nx})^n}{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, real-numbers

I was looking for Convergence and Divergence of sequence which is represented by

$$\frac{a+x}{1!}+\frac{({a+2x})^2}{2!}+\frac{({a+3x})^3}{3!}+....\frac{({a+nx})^n}{n!}$$

to that end I tried $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{T_{n+1}}{T_{n}}=\Biggr(\frac{(a+(n+1)x)^{(n+1)} n!}{(a+nx)^{n}(n+1)!}\Biggr)$ which simplifies to 
$$\frac{a+(n+1)x}{n+1} \Biggr(\frac{(a+(n+1)x)}{a+nx}\Biggr)^{n}$$ and after numerous steps we are left with

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \Biggr(\frac{a}{n+1} +x \Biggr) \Rightarrow x$$

**When I checked the solution for this, it says the series is convergent for $x \lt \frac{1}{e} $ and divergent for $x \ge \frac{1}{e}$**

I don't know where and how they arrived at that conclusion so just want some inputs on how to tackle this problem. Thanks for your help and happy new year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\frac {T_{n+1}} {T_n} =\frac {a+(n+1)x} {n+1} (1+\frac  x{1+nx})^{n}  \to ex$. Apply ratio test. What you have missed is the part $(1+\frac  x{1+nx})^{n}$ whose limit is $e$. [ $(1+\frac x {1+nx})^{n}=e^{n\log (1+\frac x {1+nx})}]$ and $\log (1+t) \sim t$ as $t \to 0$].

Comment: thanks, that was helpful. Regards. Sid